# How to access extra parameters in json file in extjs4?

Tags: json, extjs, yii

i am working in extjs4 MVC plus yii framework.I am getting stuck at a point which is how to access extra parameters in jason file coming from server and handle it to client side in extjs4.
My code:-
1) My json file is:--

```
{
    'users': [
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "userName": 'Who will win the series11111111?',
            "message":"You are welcome",
        }
    ]
}
```

2) My userModel class in extjs4 :--
In this file there is no any 'message' attribute available.

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.sn.UserModel',{

extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: ['userId','userName','password'],
proxy:
{
    type:'ajax',
    api:
    {
        read:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
        create:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
    },//end of api
    reader:
    {
        type:'json',
        root:'users'
    },//end of reader
    writer:
    {
        type:'json',
        root:'records',
    },//End of writer
}//end of proxy
});
```

3)And here is my view file where I am going to access userName and message fields coming from json file.

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view...',
        {
                extend:'Ext.view.View',
                store:'kp.UserStore',
                config:
                {
                    tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                        '<div id="main">'+
                        '</br>'+
                        '<b>userName :-</b> {userName}</br>'+
                        '<b>message :-</b> {message}</br>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</tpl>',
                    itemSelector:'div.main',    
                }
        });// End of login class
```

But its not working.It  display userName field value but not displaying message field value.

Actually I want to access a message field which is not persent in model class in extjs4. Is it correct to access to this type of fields having no any relationship? How can I access this type of fields. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Ext.data.Model` only knows about the fields it has defined. This is clear from the examples [in the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model).

If you want message to be available to your view, it must also be available from your model:

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.sn.UserModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['userId', 'userName', 'password', 'message'],
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.This changes solves the problem but is there any other way to access this type of fields without including in model field?